# How do I manually insert my signature in Thunderbird in Ubuntu?

Tags: thunderbird, mail

How can I manually add my signature in Thunderbird ?
I have set up my Thunderbird signature and it works perfect on my new messages and replies and forwards. But , sometimes I need to edit the forwards and don't want my signature in the middle or at the top of the message. So I delete it and edit what I want. Then I want to insert it at the bottom. But can't find any option to insert signature manually.

Thunderbird 17.0.2
Ubuntu 12.04.01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you want could be the addon [Quicktext](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quicktext/) available from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quicktext/ where you can find detailed info.

Basically it allows you to create all sorts of template texts (also in HTML format) which you can then insert into anywhere in your messages from a menu in the compose window.

Comment: Works perfect , thanx Sadi